# SQL Server 2014 remote connection listening port

Tags: sql-server-2014, remote-connections

I am trying to allow my SQL Server 2014 Enterprise to accept remote connections.

I followed this guide [Here](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/)

But I am not getting the same result as shown in their screen shot, which show connection as ESTABLISHED. mine shows only listening. Please help.

Help please if there are any suggestions.

Here is my screen shot

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIicG.png)

Comment: ESTABLISHED means that something is connected to the database. Since I can't see anything in the guide about that, I suspect their screenshot is misleading.

Comment: Okay thanks.  So the only way i could know for sure is to connect remotely and see if it works